# centering a link between two blocks and making the text white/ css

Tags: css, colors, background-color, positioning, centering

Trying to center link between block 3 and block 2 and make it at the top.
Also, the text is suppose to be white with a blue background.

Can not get it centered and inline with the top of the two block and the text is a purple color instead of white, it's like the blue is filtering the white text.

I stink at css and need some help please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling 
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="block2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you 
go to work every day and focus on being 
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, 
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters 
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never 
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>


body{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10em ;
  border: 2px solid black ;
  height: 25em;

}

#three {
  display: inline-block;
  left:1%;
  width: 12em;
  margin-top: .25em;
  margin-left: .25em;
  border: 7px solid orange;
}

#link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  background-color:  blue;
  color: white;
  width: 7em;
  }

#two {
  float: right;
  right: 75%;
  width: 12em;
  margin-top: .25em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  border: 7px solid green;
}



#four {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8.25em;
  width: 12em;
  margin-bottom: 12em;
  margin-left: .25em;
  border: 7px solid yellow;
  }
  
#one {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 17em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  left: 70.50%;
  width: 12em;
  border: 7px  solid blue;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm working on a solution for you right now, and I'm wondering, is your intent for each of the 4 boxes to be in the respected corner of the container box at all times?

Answer (score 0):

Add color to `a` tag instead of `#link`

```css
#three {
  display: inline-block;
  left:1%;
  width: 12em;
  margin-top: .25em;
  margin-left: .25em;
  border: 7px solid orange;
}

#link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  background-color:  blue;
  width: 7em;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  }
#link a{
color: white;
}

#two {
  float: right;
  right: 75%;
  width: 12em;
  margin-top: .25em;
  margin-right: .25em;
  border: 7px solid green;
}



#four {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8.25em;
  width: 12em;
  margin-bottom: 12em;
  margin-left: .25em;
  border: 7px solid yellow;
  }
  
#one {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 17em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  left: 70.50%;
  width: 12em;
  border: 7px  solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you 
go to work every day and focus on being 
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, 
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters 
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never 
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get your link to change colors, as Master.Deep has stated you need to add the `a` tag to `#link` like so:

```
#link a{
color: white;
}
```

There are many ways to center something and bring something to the top.  I changed your code around a little bit in order to achieve this and to fix some position issues that you have.  Pretty much what I did was wrap everything into a container, made that container have `position: relative;` then set your 4 boxes to their respective corners using `position: absolute;` on each of them and using the appropriate `left right top bottom` tags to do so. Then I placed your link to the top with `vertical-align: top;` and centered it with `text-align: top;` in the container.

Please see this example:

```css
.container{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10em ;
  border: 2px solid black ;
  height: 25em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#three {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12em;
  border: 7px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: .25em;
}

#link {
  display: inline-block;
  
  background-color:  blue;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 7em;
  }
  
#link a {
  color: white;
}  

#two {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 12em;
  margin: .25em;
  border: 7px solid green;
}

#four {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12em;
  border: 7px solid yellow;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: .25em;
  }
  
#one {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12em;
  margin: .25em;
  border: 7px  solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <!-- Do not change this file - add your CSS styling 
       rules to the blocks.css file included below -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="block2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="one">
Turns out you have a really fun time if you 
go to work every day and focus on being 
silly and funny and happy! - Hannah Murray
</div>
<div id="two">
All you need in this life is ignorance and confidence, 
and then success is sure. - Mark Twain
</div>
<div id="three">
Well, if crime fighters fight crime and fire fighters 
fight fire, what do freedom fighters fight? They never 
mention that part to us, do they? - George Carlin
</div>
<div id="four">
Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events;
small minds discuss people. - Eleanor Roosevelt
</div>
<p id="link">
<a href="https://www.brainyquote.com/" target="_blank">
Brainy Quote
</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```